# Remove Windows Network in "Browse Network" on Ubuntu Mate 18.04 LTS

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager, mate, caja

I don't know if this is since I use Ubuntu 18.04 but there is a place Network with Browse Network and Windows Network in it. I did not have samba installed and deleted all configuration files of it in /ect (I don't know why there are configuration files at all if I didn't install this application). I also did never use any Windows Networks at all and want this place to disappear if possible.

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change this behavior by removing packages, as it is non-conditionally programmed.

See relevant [source code fragment](https://github.com/mate-desktop/caja/blob/1.20/src/caja-places-sidebar.c#L883).

This is a legacy of Nautilus.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly this is just a usual behavior under Ubuntu Mate and I have not to worry about it and just leave it as it is?

Comment: Leaving it as is looks the best solution, right :)

Comment: Thanks again for your help!